# Select most important variables in terms of their contributions to PCA in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pca, apache-spark-ml

I am conducting Principal Component Analysis in Spark Scala.

My output only display the principal component score vectors. But (1) how can I get displayed the principal component loadings and (2) select the variables that contribute to the most extent to the 1st and 2nd components(i.e., have particularly high loadings on the components). I suggest to look at the first two components as they usually capture the most variance.

Any help & advice appreciated!

What I implemented so far:

```
// import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{PCA, VectorAssembler, StandardScaler}
// import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors

   val dataset = (spark.createDataFrame(
   Seq((1.2, 1.3, 1.7, 1.9), (2.2, 2.3, 2.7, 2.9), (3.2, 3.3, 3.5, 3.7))
   ).toDF("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4"))    

   val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
   .setInputCols(Array("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4"))
   .setOutputCol("features")

   val output = assembler.transform(dataset) 

 // Normalizing each feature to have a zero mean

   val scaler = new StandardScaler()
    .setInputCol("features")
    .setOutputCol("scaledFeatures")
    .setWithStd(false)
    .setWithMean(true)

  val scalerModel = scaler.fit(output)

  val scaledData = scalerModel.transform(output)


 // Compute PCA on a vector of features 

// Display the principal component score vectors

 val pca = new PCA()
  .setInputCol("scaledFeatures")
  .setOutputCol("pcaFeatures")
  .setK(2)
  .fit(scaledData)

 // ? How to extract the variables contributing most to principal components?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented a class in python which computes primarily everything related to principal components in pyspark. I recognize that your code is in scala but you can have a look if it is of any help. The implementation of the class is as follows:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.context import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler,PCA,StandardScaler
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
from pyspark.ml.param import Param,Params
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.mllib.common import callMLlibFunc, JavaModelWrapper
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import RowMatrix
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import _convert_to_vector, Vectors, Matrix, DenseMatrix
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, col, explode, struct, lit, udf, sum, when,rowNumber,avg,pow,sqrt,mean,log,desc
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import SparseVector, DenseVector, VectorUDT
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import RegressionEvaluator
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
import time, os, sys, json, math
import datetime as dt
import subprocess
import getpass
import pdb
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from copy import copy
from numpy.linalg import eigh
import itertools

class princomp:
    def __init__(self,n=5,std=True,prefix='pcomp'):
        self.n=n
        self.std=std
        self.prefix=prefix
        self.cols = [self.prefix+str(i) for i in list(range(1,self.n+1))]
        self.inputcol = "std_features"
        self.outputcol = "pca_features"
        self.vars = 'all'
        self.model = PCA(k=self.n,inputCol=self.inputcol,outputCol=self.outputcol)
        self.components = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame([0]))
        self.projections = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame([0]))
        self.result = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame([0]))
    def helpme(self):
        print ('|-- Please note that output_parameters will have null values before calling the fit method')
        print ('|-- n : input_parameter : sets the number of principal components, default = 5')
        print ('|-- std : input_parameter : True/False value specifying whether to standardize the principal components, default = True')
        print ('|-- prefix : input_parameter : string specifying the prefix for columns of principal components , default = pcomp')
        print ('|-- vars : input_parameter : list of variable names to be used for principal components, default = all')
        print ('|-- components : output_parameter : pandas dataframe of coefficients of different input columns for computing principal components')
        print ('|-- result : output_parameter : spark dataframe of original variables joined with projections of principal components')
        print ('|-- covariance : output_parameter : Numpy array of the covariance matrix')
        print ('|-- eigvals : output_parameter : Numpy array of all eigenvalues')
        print ('|-- eigvecs : output_parameter : Numpy array of all eigenvectors')
        print ('|-- varianceexplained : output_parameter : variance explained by the n principal components')
        print ('|-- outputcompfile(file) : method : outputs the components matrix to the specified file')
        print ('|-- fit(inputdf,myfeatures) : method : fit method which computes all output parameters')
    # SET methods
    def setn(self,val):
        self.n = val
        self.cols = [self.prefix+str(i) for i in list(range(1,self.n+1))]
        self.model = PCA(k=self.n,inputCol=self.inputcol,outputCol=self.outputcol)
    def setstd(self,val):
        self.std = val
    def setprefix(self,val):
        self.prefix=val
        self.cols = [self.prefix+str(i) for i in list(range(1,self.n+1))]
    def setcols(self,val):
        self.cols = val
    def setinputcol(self,val):
        self.inputcol = val
        self.model = PCA(k=self.n,inputCol=self.inputcol,outputCol=self.outputcol)
    def setoutputcol(self,val):
        self.outputcol = val
        self.model = PCA(k=self.n,inputCol=self.inputcol,outputCol=self.outputcol)
    def setvars(self,val):
        self.vars = val
    def setmodel(self,val):
        self.model = val
    def setcomponents(self,val):
        self.components=val
    def setprojections(self,val):
        self.projections=val
    def setresult(self,val):
        self.result = val
    # GET methods
    def getn(self):
        return self.n
    def getstd(self):
        return self.std
    def getprefix(self):
        return self.prefix
    def getcols(self):
        return self.cols
    def getinputcol(self):
        return self.inputcol
    def getoutputcol(self):
        return self.outputcol
    def getvars(self):
        return self.vars
    def getmodel(self):
        return self.model
    def getcomponents(self):
        return self.components
    def getprojections(self):
        return self.projections
    def getresult(self):
        return self.result
    # CORE methods
    def vectorizedf(inputdf,vars='all'):
        """Returns the input spark dataframe with an additional column of dense vector features"""
        if vars=='all':
            myfeatures = inputdf.columns
        else:
            myfeatures=vars

        assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols = myfeatures,outputCol="features")
        assembled = assembler.transform(inputdf)

        as_dense = udf(
            lambda v: DenseVector(v.toArray()) if v is not None else None,
            VectorUDT()
        )

        df_dense = assembled.withColumn("features1", as_dense(assembled.features))
        df_dense2 = df_dense.drop("features")
        df_dense3 = df_dense2.withColumnRenamed("features1","features")
        return df_dense3
    def outputcompfile(self,filewlocation):
        """ Outputs the loading of principal components to the file specified"""
        df = self.components
        df.to_csv(filewlocation,index=False)
        print ("Component matrix is now available at the location : "+filewlocation)
    def identity(self):
        """ Outputs an identity matrix in the form of features column in a dataframe"""
        iden = np.identity(len(self.vars)).tolist()
        rddi = sc.parallelize(iden)
        df_identity = rddi.map(lambda line:Row(std_features=Vectors.dense(line))).toDF()
        return df_identity
    def fit(self,inputdf,myfeatures):
        """ Fits the input dataframe in a PCA model with the given features """
        start_time = time.time()      # Start Timer
        if myfeatures=='all':
            self.vars = inputdf.columns
        else:
            self.vars = myfeatures
        # vectorize and scale
        df_dense = self.vectorizedf(inputdf,self.vars)
        df_normalized = self.scalemeanstd(df_dense)
        # Compute covariance matrix, eigenvalues and eigenvectors
        dfzeromean = df_normalized.select(self.inputcol)
        self.covariance = dfzeromean.map(lambda x:np.outer(x,x)).sum()/dfzeromean.count()
        col1 = self.covariance.shape[1]
        eigvals,eigvecs = eigh(self.covariance)
        inds = np.argsort(eigvals)
        self.eigvals = eigvals[inds[-1:-(col1+1):-1]]
        self.eigvecs = -1*eigvecs.T[inds[-1:-(col1+1):-1]]
        self.varianceexplained = np.sum(self.eigvals[0:self.n])/np.sum(self.eigvals)
        # Fit PCA model
        model1 = self.model.fit(df_normalized)
        df_features = model1.transform(df_normalized)
        # Compute components and put in a pandas dataframe
        df_identity = self.identity()
        components = model1.transform(df_identity)
        components = components.withColumnRenamed('pca_features','components')
        edf_rdd = components.select("components").rdd.map(lambda x: tuple(x.components.toArray().tolist()))
        edf_pandas = edf_rdd.toDF(self.cols).toPandas()
        comp_ind = sqlContext.createDataFrame([Row(industries=self.vars)])
        comp_ind_pandas = comp_ind.select(explode(comp_ind.industries).alias("Variable")).toPandas()
        self.components = pd.concat([comp_ind_pandas,edf_pandas],axis=1)
        # Compute and standardize projections if self.std = True
        if self.std:
            projections1=self.scalemeanstd(df_features,inputcol = "pca_features",outputcol = "projections")
        else:
            projections1 = df_features.withColumnRenamed('pca_features','projections')
        # Prepare data for output
        self.projections = projections1.select('projections')
        drop_list = ['features','std_features','pca_features']
        projections2 = projections1.select([c for c in projections1.columns if c not in drop_list])
        l = ['x.'+c for c in inputdf.columns]
        cst = '['+",".join(l)+']'
        final_df = projections1.rdd.map(lambda x: tuple(eval(cst))+tuple(x.projections.toArray().tolist())).toDF(inputdf.columns+self.cols)
        self.result = final_df
        print("PCA fitting took a total of %s seconds " % (time.time() - start_time))
```

The way to use this class would be as follows :

```
fs = ep.princomp(n=15)
fs.fit(df,select_features) # here select_features is the list of columns that you wish to perform PCA on
fs.outputcompfile('/some/output/location/components.csv')
print (fs.eigvals)
print (fs.varianceexplained)
```

So you can output the components file at a location which would have all the factor loadings. Using that file you can find out all the variables that contribute the most to the first n principal components.

Comment: Thank you, Gaurav! Great! I will have a look at it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The [PCAModel documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.PCAModel) says `pca.pc` will give you a `DenseMatrix` whose columns are the principal components.

I guess it does not specify whether the columns are in order. I would guess that they are, but you might want to check.

From there you can do `.colIter` to get the columns individually and pick the entries with highest absolute value to see which variables contribute the most.

Comment: Thx for help! :-)

Comment: [`explainedVariance`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.PCAModel@explainedVariance:org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector) will probably be helpful here.  Sadly, however, `linalg.Vector` does not support `argsort`, which would make the rest of the job easier.